# Glob does not find symlinks

Tags: c++, linux, glob

I am using c++ with:

```
#include <glob.h>
```

I have the folder:

```
/test/foo -> bar
```

bar does not exist.

I just want glob to return:

```
/test/foo
```

But glob returns error 3: GLOB_NOMATCH

If it try with

```
/test/foo
```

glob finds it fine.

I'm using:

```
  std::string pattern = "/test/*";
  glob_t g;
  err = glob(pattern.c_str(),
          0, NULL, &g);
```

Do I need a different flag or asterisk pattern to find symlinks?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure the pathname in the pattern is correct?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure, also, using echo works fine and I get: /test/foo

Comment: What is `errno` when this happens?

Comment: The err is 3 GLOB_NOMATCH - is that what you meant?

Comment: The difference in the files I see is the permissions are: -rw-r--r-- for the 'normal' file - and it's lrwxrwxrwx for the link. The directory is drwxr-xr-x

Comment: No, that's `err`, not `errno`.

Comment: Use `if (err != 0) { perror("glob"); }` to see the value of `errno`.

Comment: That's the normal permissions for a symlink.

Comment: Yeah, errno is 2

Comment: The permissions on the directory should be the ones that matter.  At least on my machine, creating an empty file foo and removing all permissions still works, as long as the directory permissions work.  Have you tried opening the directory with opendir and enumerating its contents with readdir?

Comment: However, I am running it as part of a program - when I use a file in the directory err is 0 and errno is still 2

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only flag that will cause `glob()` to test anything but the filename matching is `GLOB_ONLYDIR`. I can't imagine any reason why it cares whether the symlink resolves.

Comment: Try using `strace` to see what it's calling when you call `glob()`.

Comment: OK, I will do, but I have to leave it for tonight, I thought this would be an easy fix...Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: errno==2 is ENOENT.  Something is trying to resolve a path that doesn't exist.  I'm curious about whether this happens with a local subdirectory, say if "test" is under your home.

Comment: So I am on a remote PC - and the file structure here is complicated - but I was using my user directory. Can I clear the errno prior to running glob (to make sure that my use of glob is really the thing causing the errno to set)

Comment: Is it a remote file system that's network mounted?  That might affect behavior around symlinks.  Is your user directory really "/"?  That's pretty odd even if you're root.

Comment: Running out of ideas, especially because I can't make it happen here.  Two suggestions would be to see what happens if you enumerate the directory entries with readdir and (very long shot) make sure the asterisk is really an asterisk if you're editor is saving unicode (hey, I said "very long shot").

Comment: If the file system is a network file system of some kind, that could also affect glob's ability to use wildcards to search directories, depending on the implementation.

Comment: `glob()` isn't documented as setting `errno`; whatever value it has might end up being helpful, but isn't definitive in tracking down the problem (because its default behavior is to try to continue after errors any errno might be from a *different* issue). Not like a `strace` could be.

Comment: Or making use of the `errfunc` callback, as that *does* get a relevant error number passed to it.

Comment: So I found an answer of sorts for this, I was using a system which didn't have a patch applied to glob:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=126460

Thanks for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on directory "test".  This kind of thing is exactly what would happen if you have execute permission (a.k.a. search permission) on the directory but not read.

glob() will need read permissions to expand the *, but to look up a specific name without any expansions will require only that the "x" bit be set.

I ran this little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glob.h>

int main() {
  glob_t g;
   int err;

   err = glob("./test/*", 0, NULL, &g);

   if (err == GLOB_NOMATCH) printf("no match\n");
   else {
      for (int i = 0; i < g.gl_pathc; i++) {
         printf("match %d:  %s\n", i, g.gl_pathv[i]);
      }
   }

   err = glob("./test/foo", 0, NULL, &g);

   if (err == GLOB_NOMATCH) printf("no match\n");
   else {
      for (int i = 0; i < g.gl_pathc; i++) {
         printf("match %d:  %s\n", i, g.gl_pathv[i]);
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If test has these permissions:

```
d--x------ 2 thomask users 4096 Dec 15 14:10 test/
```

then the output is:

```
 no match
 match 0:  ./test/foo
```

If test has these permissions:

```
 drwx------ 2 thomask users 4096 Dec 15 14:10 test/
```

or these permissions:

```
 dr-x------ 2 thomask users 4096 Dec 15 14:10 test/
```

then the output is:

```
 match 0:  ./test/foo
 match 0:  ./test/foo
```

The exact difference in permissions that matters depends, of course, on whether you own the file or are in the group that is set for the file.

In each case, I  used a local subdirectory named "test" rather than a subdirectory under the root directory, and it contains a single dangling link named "foo" as you specified above.

Comment: Read permissions are set on the directory (for all users):

drwxr-xr-x

Comment: Running the same code I gave above but with an absolute path and the permissions set as you describe, I don't see the behavior you describe.  I'm doing this compiling as C using gcc on Arch linux.  Are you on some non-linux or not-really linux platform (like cygwin) maybe?

Comment: Nope, it's linux (CentOS) using gcc compiler. 

It's odd that echo /test/* works fine.

Comment: It works fine when the directory just contains, foo, but with foo -> bar it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually a g++ compilation.

Comment: The difference in the files I see is  the permissions are: -rw-r--r-- for the 'normal' file - and it's lrwxrwxrwx for the link. The directory is drwxr-xr-x